# Create a view that shows cases for a queue and an additional user

Tags: case, view

I want to create a view that displays all cases that have "Case Queue" and "Mark Thompson" assigned as their owners. 
I have tried this by setting the filter criteria to

```
'owner equals case queue'
'OR'
'owner equals mark thompson'
```

but it doesn't seem to work. 
is it not possible to do this?
Tia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this in my dev org using the below settings.  Use Owner Name for the Queue and Owner Last Name for the user.  If its a common Last Name, then you can use First name as well.

[image]

> **EDIT**

If you want to use first and last name, then you just need to adjust it like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have done similar list views (although not for the Case object) using "Owner Alias" as my filter criteria field. It should show up as "Case Owner Alias". Works great for other objects so should work with Cases! This tidbit and Chris' advice should solve your issue.